# AStar Search Error in PriorityQueue in java

Tags: java, a-star

I have run my code to get shorted distance from two point which we giving.my grid & everything working suddenly there got issue with jave PriorityQueue error n another error in my code i cant figure out what is it.help me to sort out this.
I have two classes called pathfinding & algo code separately.I'm passing 4 values to methord,start point n ending point ,grid size & blocked areas.

```
public class PathFindingOnSquaredGrid {

// given an N-by-N matrix of open cells, return an N-by-N matrix
// of cells reachable from the top
public static boolean[][] flow(boolean[][] open) {
    int N = open.length;

    boolean[][] full = new boolean[N][N];
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        flow(open, full, 0, j);
    }

    return full;
}

// determine set of open/blocked cells using depth first search
public static void flow(boolean[][] open, boolean[][] full, int i, int j) {
    int N = open.length;

    // base cases
    if (i < 0 || i >= N) return;    // invalid row
    if (j < 0 || j >= N) return;    // invalid column
    if (!open[i][j]) return;        // not an open cell
    if (full[i][j]) return;         // already marked as open

    full[i][j] = true;

    flow(open, full, i+1, j);   // down
    flow(open, full, i, j+1);   // right
    flow(open, full, i, j-1);   // left
    flow(open, full, i-1, j);   // up
}

// does the system percolate?
public static boolean percolates(boolean[][] open) {
    int N = open.length;

    boolean[][] full = flow(open);
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        if (full[N-1][j]) return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

// does the system percolate vertically in a direct way?
    public static boolean percolatesDirect(boolean[][] open) {
        int N = open.length;

```
    boolean[][] full = flow(open);
    int directPerc = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        if (full[N-1][j]) {
            // StdOut.println("Hello");
            directPerc = 1;
            int rowabove = N-2;
            for (int i = rowabove; i >= 0; i--) {
                if (full[i][j]) {
                    // StdOut.println("i: " + i + " j: " + j + " " + full[i][j]);
                    directPerc++;
                }
                else break;
            }
        }
    }

    // StdOut.println("Direct Percolation is: " + directPerc);
    if (directPerc == N) return true; 
    else return false;
}

// draw the N-by-N boolean matrix to standard draw
public static void show(boolean[][] a, boolean which) {
    int N = a.length;
    StdDraw.setXscale(-1, N);;
    StdDraw.setYscale(-1, N);
    StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.BLACK);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            if (a[i][j] == which)
                StdDraw.square(j, N-i-1, .5);
            else StdDraw.filledSquare(j, N-i-1, .5);
}

// draw the N-by-N boolean matrix to standard draw, including the points A (x1, y1) and B (x2,y2) to be marked by a circle
public static void show(boolean[][] a, boolean which, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
    int N = a.length;
    StdDraw.setXscale(-1, N);;
    StdDraw.setYscale(-1, N);
    StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.BLACK);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            if (a[i][j] == which)
                if ((i == x1 && j == y1) ||(i == x2 && j == y2)) {
                    StdDraw.circle(j, N-i-1, .5);
                }
                else StdDraw.square(j, N-i-1, .5);
            else StdDraw.filledSquare(j, N-i-1, .5);
}

// return a random N-by-N boolean matrix, where each entry is
// true with probability p
public static boolean[][] random(int N, double p) {
    boolean[][] a = new boolean[N][N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            a[i][j] = StdRandom.bernoulli(p);
    return a;
}


// test client
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // boolean[][] open = StdArrayIO.readBoolean2D();

    // The following will generate a 10x10 squared grid with relatively few obstacles in it
    // The lower the second parameter, the more obstacles (black cells) are generated
    boolean[][] randomlyGenMatrix = random(10, 0.8);

    StdArrayIO.print(randomlyGenMatrix);
    show(randomlyGenMatrix, true);

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("The system percolates: " + percolates(randomlyGenMatrix));

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("The system percolates directly: " + percolatesDirect(randomlyGenMatrix));
    System.out.println();

    // Reading the coordinates for points A and B on the input squared grid.

    // THIS IS AN EXAMPLE ONLY ON HOW TO USE THE JAVA INTERNAL WATCH
    // Start the clock ticking in order to capture the time being spent on inputting the coordinates
    // You should position this command accordingly in order to perform the algorithmic analysis
    Stopwatch timerFlow = new Stopwatch();

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter i for A > ");
    int Ai = in.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter j for A > ");
    int Aj = in.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter i for B > ");
    int Bi = in.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter j for B > ");
    int Bj = in.nextInt();

 // THIS IS AN EXAMPLE ONLY ON HOW TO USE THE JAVA INTERNAL WATCH
    // Stop the clock ticking in order to capture the time being spent on inputting the coordinates
    // You should position this command accordingly in order to perform the algorithmic analysis
    StdOut.println("Elapsed time = " + timerFlow.elapsedTime());







    // System.out.println("Coordinates for A: [" + Ai + "," + Aj + "]");
    // System.out.println("Coordinates for B: [" + Bi + "," + Bj + "]");
    ArrayList<int[]> blockList=new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < randomlyGenMatrix.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < randomlyGenMatrix[i].length; j++) {
            if(randomlyGenMatrix[i][j]){
                blockList.add(new int[]{i,j});
            }
        }            
    }

    int[][] blockArray=new int[blockList.size()][2];
    for (int i = 0; i < blockList.size(); i++) {
        blockArray[i] = blockList.get(i);
        System.out.println("############"+blockList.get(i));
       // blockArray[j] = blockList.get(j);
    }

    //show(randomlyGenMatrix, true, Ai, Aj, Bi, Bj,);
```

show(randomlyGenMatrix, true, Ai, Aj, Bi, Bj);
        AStarCopied.test(10,10, Ai, Aj, Bi, Bj, blockArray);

```
}
```

}

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: its giving error :(